# Can I pay to return my opponent's Shackles to their hand?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If my opponent plays [Shackles](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bShackles%5d) enchanting one of my creatures, can I pay the {W} cost to return it to their hand?

Answer (score 4):

**No**.

Activated abilities can normally only be activated by the controller of the permanent with the ability. When your opponent plays Shackles, even when it is attached to one of your creatures, they are still the controller of Shackles.

> 303.4e An Aura’s controller is separate from the enchanted object’s controller or the enchanted player; the two need not be the same. If an Aura enchants an object, changing control of the object doesn’t change control of the Aura, and vice versa. Only the Aura’s controller can activate its abilities.
>
> 110.2. A permanent’s owner is the same as the owner of the card that represents it (unless it’s a token; see rule 110.5a). **A permanent’s controller is, by default, the player under whose control it entered the battlefield.** Every permanent has a controller.
>
> 602.2. To activate an ability is to put it onto the stack and pay its costs, so that it will eventually resolve and have its effect. **Only an object’s controller (or its owner, if it doesn’t have a controller) can activate its activated ability unless the object specifically says otherwise.**